# How do I install Xenapp 6 client components?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have got Xenapp 6 server running and have published an app.  Now I cannot find any information about setting the client side up.

I remember in the older Citrix Presentation Server, you install the ICA client, you get Program Neighbourhood and can launch apps from there.  Can't seem to find it in Xenapp 6.

I tried downloading and installing Xenapp plugin.  It installs, but I have not idea how to launch it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From xenapp 11 the feature of program neighborhood is not available anymore,
instead you either use Citrix Web Interface (nFuse) from a browser or you can create a site in Web Interface management console that is called PNAgent site, after you create the site you can configure the site in the Citrix Icon near the tray,
You should have AD authentication to simplify things.